# Как проверить работоспособность apikey?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пои подключении API Яндекс.Карт
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=<ваш API-ключ>
<ваш API-ключ> вводит пользователь.
Есть ли возможность проверить правильность ключа перед тем как выполнять код связанный с картой?

Comment: А объясните, что за сценарий? Ключ по идее единожды устанавливает разработчик сервиса, который может и проверить его работоспособность.

Comment: Карта используется в виджете доставки и ключ устанавливает администратор сайта в админке. При этом он может забыть его указать или указать не верно. Хотелось бы при запуске виджета вывести корректное сообщение об ошибке, что необходимо указать корректный API Key.

Comment: Понятно. Боюсь, в таком сценарии не получится проверить ключ автоматически. Запрос с ключом может вернуть ошибку, даже если ключ в порядке (но пользователь заблокирован, превысил дневной лимит или привязал ключ к другому домену).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать запрос к API например для получения координат с проверенно рабочими данными для проверки ключа:

```js
    ymaps.geocode('Москва').then(function (res) {
        // Выполняем код использующий API
    }, function (err) {
        alert('API Key неверный.');
    }
```

Но в данном случае ошибка запроса может произойти и по другим причинам.